# PHP preg_replace has error. How can I found out the reason?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$string = '## aaa                                                                 bbb';
$pattern = '/^(\n)?\s{0,}#{1,6}\s+| {0,}(\n)?\s{0,}#{0,} {0,}(\n)?\s{0,}$/';
$replacement = '$1$2$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

If the space between "aaa" and "bbb" is around 50 (or less), I DO get the correct result.  BUT if I increase the number, say there are 100 space between "aaa" and "bbb".  I get null.  How can I find out the reason?

Comment: What is an error here? Please provide requirements your pattern should meet. BTW, it looks like a pattern following `^a|b$` logic. Shouldn't it be `^(?:a|b)$`? If you try `'/^(?:(\n)?\s{0,}#{1,6}\s+| {0,}(\n)?\s{0,}#{0,} {0,}(\n)?\s{0,})$/'` will it work as intended?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bvmTHC/2 - see the link on the right about *catastrophic backtracking*

Comment: That is right, the pattern is very inefficient as the quantified patterns that match the same things are separated here with optional subpatterns (also patterns that are `*` quantified). The second branch is the culprit here. However, fixing it is too hard due to the fact we do not know what you need to do. Trying to simplify it, I came to [`^\s*#{1,6}\s+|\s*(?:#\s*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/kbZjCz/1). Not sure it is what will work though.

Comment: I am not good at regex.  The patten is got from: https://github.com/stiang/remove-markdown/blob/master/index.js  (please see line: 48).  I know its JS. I tried both JS and PHP.  Both working if there are less spaces, and both NOT working if there are lots of spaces.

Comment: @KamanWu See my answer below with a fix for both JS and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern matches two alternatives, one `^(\n)?\s*#{1,6}\s+` and the other  `*(\n)?\s*#* *(\n)?\s*$`.

The first one is OK, though it is advised to make `\n` optional rather than making the whole group optional.

The second one,  `*(\n)?\s*#* *(\n)?\s*$`, is a very inefficient pattern because there are `\s*` patterns that follow an optional `\n` pattern that is in its turn preceded with a  `*` pattern. When there is no `\n`, `\s*` may "fall into"  `*` and that [leads to catastrophical backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/5txcho/1) when part of the pattern matches but the final subpatterns fail.

So, you may use

```
/^(\n?)\s*#{1,6}\s+| *(?:(\n)\s*)?#* *(?:(\n)\s*)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5txcho/3)

The crucial point here is `(?:(\n)\s*)?` parts where `\n` is *obligatory* and will only be tried after all regular spaces are matched with  `*` and then `\s*` will only be tried if there is `\n` before, thus, ensuring no subpattern will fall into the other.